# How do I compare values?

Tags: python

I'm trying to compare the values between 2 stacks of numbers. I'm trying to print all the values that match and then print all the values that don't match. I'm just trying to see if there's a shorter stack implementation I can do besides the one I currently have or how can I make the one I currently have work?

```
    stack1 = [5,12,7,89,8,14,34,6,15,26,7,45]
    stack2 = [9,23,14,8,12,76,9,1,34,25,90,8]
    bothStacks = [stack1, stack2]

    def push(a):    
      bothStacks.append(a)

    push('a')
    push('b')
    push('c')

    print('\nInitial stack\n')
    print(bothStacks)

    print('\nElements popped from stack:\n')
    print(bothStacks.pop())
    print(bothStacks.pop())
    print(bothStacks.pop())

    print('\nStack after elements are popped:\n')
    print(bothStacks)

    #the expected outcome should look like this: 
    Stack 1: 5,12,7,89,8,14,34,6,15,26,7,45
    Stack 2: 9,23,14,8,12,76,9,1,34,25,90,8
    Numbers in both stacks: 8,12,14,34
    Numbers only in Stack 1: 5,7,89,6,15,26,7,45
    Numbers only in Stack 2: 9,23,76,9,1,25,90
```

Comment: "match" in what sense?

Comment: `bothStacks` contains exactly two elements.  (Both are lists.)  After you do `bothStacks.pop()` twice, your stack will be empty.  Are you trying to push and pop elements onto both stacks in one call?

Comment: If neither will have duplicates then set.symmetric_difference will do this already

Comment: The values "that match", should match only by value or also by position? Can you provide the expected result for your example?

Comment: btw, your `push` function will raise an error, and doesn't really make any sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
stack1 = [5,12,7,89,8,14,34,6,15,26,7,45]
stack2 = [9,23,14,8,12,76,9,1,34,25,90,8]

common_values = set(stack1).intersection(stack2)
uniques_stack1 = [i for i in stack1 if i not in common_values]
uniques_stack2 = [i for i in stack2 if i not in common_values]

print('Numbers in both stacks: ', repr(common_values)[1:-1])  #8,12,14,34
print('Numbers only in Stack 1: ', repr(uniques_stack1)[1:-1]) # 5,7,89,6,15,26,7,45
print('Numbers only in Stack 2: ', repr(uniques_stack2)[1:-1]) # 9,23,76,9,1,25,90

# Prints
Numbers in both stacks:  8, 34, 12, 14
Numbers only in Stack 1:  5, 7, 89, 6, 15, 26, 7, 45
Numbers only in Stack 2:  9, 23, 76, 9, 1, 25, 90
```

The `repr(some_list_of_ints)[1, -1]` is to deal with the fact that the values are `int` and not `str`, so `','.join(...)` won't straightforwardly work. Surely there's a more pythonic way and I'm too tired to see it...

Besides `intersection`, python has also `difference`, so you could do

```
uniques_stack1 = set(stack1).difference(common_values)
uniques_stack2 = set(stack2).difference(common_values)
```

But because it works with sets, it's not going to conserve the order.

I assume there's no need for order in the values common to both stacks since it won't be clear what's the order if for example one stack has `[8, ..., 34, ...]` and the other one `[34, ..., 8, ...]`. But you can always [sort](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#sorted) it so they appear as in your example.

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#set).